# NodeJS server not responding to AJAX request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, api, express

I keep getting a 404 in the networks tab when attempting the POST below. This works fine on my localhost. I can't see where I'm going wrong here. The `console.log(data)` line is working as it should be. It's just `res.end(data)` that isn't executing.

```
app.post('/wan_customers', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
   var data = {
      account: req.body['account']
   }

   await forwardCreds('GET', 'getCustomers', data).then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      return res.end(data)
   }).catch((e) => { console.log(e) })
})
```

I am sending the request from a script in the browser, shown below:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/wan_customers",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {"account": document.getElementById("portal").value},
                success: (data) => {
                    alert(data)
                    str=''
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length;++i) {
                        str += '<option value="'+data[i]+'" />'; // Storing options in variable
                    }
                    var my_list=document.getElementById("customers");
                    my_list.innerHTML = str;

                    document.getElementById("customer").placeholder = "Customers Loaded!"
                    document.getElementById("customer").setAttribute("required", "")
                    document.getElementById("devButton").removeAttribute("hidden")
                }
            })
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have different apps for frontend and backend? Can you check the base URL in the networks tab of the request?

Comment: Is there any warnings in console maybe?

Comment: Yes, we have our own domain. The base URL corresponds to it correctly. Other functional API queries are working fine - it seems to declare 404 very quickly with this one. @LuckyLuke There are no errors. The last output is the console log of the data to be sent.

Comment: Your problem probably lies in your server configuration because when you try to access website.com/wan_customers it gets rejected because nothing is handling it and returned 404 not found error in your request. Are you sure you have configured your server correctly? You might want to search a solution for `your server nodejs not found error` like nginx or apache2 or whatever you use.